# jQuery hide when clicked on anything but div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried the answers to the similair questions of this without success.

In this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h2HzN/6/

I have it set up that when you press escape it goes away using this:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $("#signup").fadeOut(250);
        $("#window").slideUp(450);
    }
});
```

but I also want it go away when you click anywhere but the black box. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do that [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/rQQkU/)

```
$(window).click(function() {
  if(this.id !== "window") {
    $("#signup").fadeOut(250);
    $("#window").slideUp(450);
  }
});

$("#window").on("click", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

For the latest fiddle you've provided,

[MODIFIED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/8P6gH/)

Latest solution for me,

```
$("#popup").add("#signup_signin a").click(function(e) {
   $("#signup").fadeIn(400);
   $("#window").slideDown(450);
   e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
       $("#signup").fadeOut(250);
       $("#window").slideUp(450);
    }
});

$(window).click(function() {
    if(this.id !== "popup") {
      $("#signup").fadeOut(250);
      $("#window").slideUp(450);
    }
});

$("#window").on("click", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

It only fades out when Esc used or clicked anywhere but the black box and the sign up button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        removeMessage();
    }
}).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('#window').length == 0 || $(e.target).prop('id') != 'window') {
        removeMessage();
    }
});

function removeMessage() {
    $("#signup").fadeOut(250);
    $("#window").slideUp(450);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2HzN/3/)

Note that checking for the closest `#window` element means that this code will work for any child element within the `#window`.

Comment: Ah very nice. What I forgot to add in the jsfiddle though is that the window appears when you click on something. When i add your solution it immediatly hides it again.  See here : http://jsfiddle.net/h2HzN/6/

Comment: @user3621590 you need to add a class to the button which makes the messagebox appear, and then add a condition to the `if` which excludes clicks from that class.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan +1, also, I modified a bit your solution... http://jsfiddle.net/h2HzN/8/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan very nice, much tidier. I'd +1 if I could :)

Comment: I just have an issue if you add an inner element inside `#window` :| which happens also in your example so... might need for a fix

Comment: what about this one? http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/8P6gH/ It only fades out when Esc used or clicked anywhere but the black box and the sign up button

Comment: @EkinHazal nice, but the `if(this.id !== "popup")` is too restrictive. In a larger project you might have more than one button to open a popup... :|

Comment: For sure @RokoC.Buljan, yet for this question looks like it's enough. But yes, I'm actually trying to find a better way because of that. I might need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way:

```
   $("div #window").click(function(e){


    return false;


});

$(document.body).click(function(){


        $("#signup").fadeOut(250);
        $("#window").slideUp(450);


})
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/syQu8/)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
$("#window").on("click", function (e) {
    //stop propagation so that it's not handled in document root.
    e.stopPropagation();
});

//if not stopped by window i.e. not clicked on #window then handle and hide.
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    $("#signup").fadeOut(250);
    $("#window").slideUp(450);
});
```

Option 2:

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if(e.target.id === 'window') return;

    $("#signup").fadeOut(250);
    $("#window").slideUp(450);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use stopPropagation():

http://jsfiddle.net/h2HzN/4/

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $("#signup").fadeOut(250);
        $("#window").slideUp(450);
    }
}).click(function(){
    $("#signup").fadeOut(250);
    $("#window").slideUp(450); 
});
//if you click within #window, the document.click will not trigger.
$("#window").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```